# Change password function doesn't work in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel-6, change-password

I am new to Laravel and PHP(I just got in this new company 1 week ago). I am trying to build a "Change password" function using Laravel 6, but for some reasons it just doesn't work. It keeps telling me 'The current password field does not match your password', even though I am sure my current password is correct. I asked my senior and he doesn't know why either lolll

Here is the part at the front end where the user edits the password:

```
<div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="title">{{ __('Password') }}</h5>
                </div>
                <form method="post" action="{{ route('profile.password', $user->id) }}" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @csrf
                        @method('put')

                        @include('alerts.success', ['key' => 'password_status'])

                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('old_password') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                            <label>{{ __('Current Password') }}</label>
                            <input type="password" name="old_password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('old_password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Current Password') }}" value="" required>
                            @include('alerts.feedback', ['field' => 'old_password'])
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                            <label>{{ __('New Password') }}</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('New Password') }}" value="" required>
                            @include('alerts.feedback', ['field' => 'password'])
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ __('Confirm New Password') }}</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('Confirm New Password') }}" value="" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary">{{ __('Change password') }}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the function within the controller to change password:

```
public function password(PasswordRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = Users::findOrFail($id);
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));

        $user->save();
        
        return back()->withPasswordStatus(__('Password successfully updated.'));
    }
```

Here is the PasswordRequest(I didn't write this part. It came with the template I'm using):

```
class PasswordRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'old_password' => ['required', 'min:4', new CurrentPasswordCheckRule],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:4', 'confirmed', 'different:old_password'],
            'password_confirmation' => ['required', 'min:4'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'old_password' => __('current password'),
        ];
    }
}
```

And here is the CurrentPasswordCheckRule:

```
class CurrentPasswordCheckRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return Hash::check($value, auth()->user()->password);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return __('The current password field does not match your password');
    }
}
```

And in case the problem arises at the registration stage, here is the code for registration:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request, Users $model)
    {

        $user = new Users();

        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->last_name = request('last_name');
        $user->first_name = request('first_name');
        $user->company_id = request('company_id');

        //image
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
  
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  

        $upload_path = 'images/';
        $profile_image_url = $upload_path. $imageName;
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

        $user->profile_image = $profile_image_url;
        //image

        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));

        $user -> save();


        return redirect()->route('pages.user_list')->withStatus(__('User successfully created.'));
    }
```

I am sorry I know here is a lot of code. Thanks in advance for any help. Ask me any questions.

Comment: so both registration and the change password do not work?

Comment: @AndySong Registration works. Only "Change password" doesn't.